# Battery not recognized in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laptop, battery

I recently installed a new GHU battery in my HP Spectre X360, but now there is no battery meter in the corner anymore. When I run sudo lshw, it says there is no battery installed. When I open Power Statistics, instead of showing a battery it shows a keyboard battery (I don't have an external keyboard installed), which I am assuming is the actual battery that is just being recognized as a keyboard. It is also not pulling any power statistics from this 'keyboard battery' either. When I run laptop-detect -v I get "We're not on a laptop. (No relevant hint found). The lshw command showed the correct computer model, but has Convertible as the description...not sure if that would matter as far as it knowing it is on a laptop and should have a battery or not. Any ideas?

Normally this isn't a huge deal, but it would be nice to see that my computer is about to shutdown on me during the few times I do actually use it not plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. Apparently, even though the ribbon cable on the battery is labeled - + -, it still matters which way it is plugged in. I unplugged the cable, flipped the connector, and plugged it back in and now it is recognizing the battery and charging it. Why they wouldn't key a connector that can only be plugged in one way I don't know, but they didn't.